# How to make a dynamic link to a pivot table value?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

On `tab1` I have a pivot table . When I double click subtotal number `256` on that `pivot table`, a new worksheet pops up with the details. Everything is just as expected.

---

On `tab2`, I have a formula in  the field `A1`  . This formula refers to the subtotal value in the pivot (from tab1)

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("theId",tab1!$A$1)
```

`A1` shows  `256` . . . exactly as in the pivot table .

---

I need to be able to doulble click this `A1` field and see a pop up worksheet with the details (as if I was clicking the pivot table)

---

The problem is `GETPIVOTDATA` returns a value only and no link or indirect reference

How can I do this ?

Comment: The pivot always is the same??? Always had the same headers???

Comment: I got a code to perform something similiar as you ask in your question. Let me show you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay, but the weekend was in the middle.
Well here is my answer to how to show the data from a pivot, just with doble click inside a cell, in another sheet that have, the `GETPIVOTDATA` formula.

Note that in my pivot, I set to "Repeat all items labels" and use a old style pivot.

See the pictures:
**For repeat all items labels**
[image]

**and the old style works better for me, and most of all, the macro (VBA)**
[image]

That been said, let's code!!

All this inside a regular module.

```
Sub getDataFromFormula(theFormulaSht As Worksheet, formulaCell As Range)
    Dim f
    Dim arrayF
    Dim i
    Dim L
    Dim iC
    Dim newArrayF() As Variant
'    Dim rowLables_Sort()
'    Dim rowLables_Sort_i()
    Dim T As Worksheet
    Dim rowRange_Labels As Range
    Dim shtPivot As Worksheet
    Dim shtPivotName
    Dim thePivot As PivotTable
    Dim numRows
    Dim numCols
    Dim colRowRange As Range
    Dim colRowSubRange As Range
    Dim First As Boolean
    Dim nR
    Dim nC
    Dim myCol
    Dim myRow
    Dim theRNG As Range

    Set T = theFormulaSht 'the sheet where the formula is

    '#####################################
    'my example formula
    '=GETPIVOTDATA("EURO",P!$A$3,"Descripcion","Ingresos Netos de Terceros ,","Mes","July","CuentaCrest","310100","Descripción Crest","Net revenue third parties","Producto","AFR","SubProducto","AFRI","TM1","Net Revenue")
    '#####################################

    T.Activate 'go!
    f = formulaCell.Formula 'get the formula
    f = Replace(f, "=GETPIVOTDATA", "") 'delete some things...
    f = Replace(f, Chr(34), "")
    f = Replace(f, ",,", ",") 'in my data, there is ,, and I need to fix this...
    f = Right(f, Len(f) - 1) 'take the formual without parentesis.
    f = Left(f, Len(f) - 1)

    '####################################
    'Restult inside "f"
    'EURO,P!$A$3,Descripcion,Ingresos Netos de Terceros ,Mes,July,CuentaCrest,310100,Descripción Crest,Net revenue third parties,Producto,AFR,SubProducto,AFRI,TM1,Net Revenue
    '####################################

    arrayF = Split(f, ",")

    '####################################
    'Restult inside arrayF
    'EURO,P!$A$3,Descripcion,Ingresos Netos de Terceros ,Mes,July,CuentaCrest,310100,Descripción Crest,Net revenue third parties,Producto,AFR,SubProducto,AFRI,TM1,Net Revenue
    '####################################

    shtPivotName = arrayF(1) 'set (just) the name of the sheet with the pivot
    shtPivotName = Left(shtPivotName, InStr(1, shtPivotName, "!") - 1)
    Set shtPivot = Sheets(shtPivotName) 'set the var with the sheet that contents the pivot
    Set thePivot = shtPivot.PivotTables(1) 'store the pivot inside

    If shtPivot.Visible = False Then 'if the sheet with the pivot is hidden... set visible.
        shtPivot.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If

    shtPivot.Activate 'go there!

    numRows = thePivot.RowRange.Rows.Count - 1 'the number of rows of the row Range
    numCols = thePivot.RowRange.Columns.Count 'here the columns of the same range
    Set rowRange_Labels = thePivot.RowRange.Resize(1, numCols)
    'with Resize get jus the labels above the RowRange (see the picture (1))

    iC = -1

    First = True

    For Each i In rowRange_Labels 'run the labels
        iC = -1 'set the counter
        If First Then 'check the flag to see if is the firt time...
            First = False 'set the flag to FALSE to go the other part of the IF next time
            Set colRowRange = Range(Cells(i.Row, i.Column), Cells(i.Row + numRows - 1, i.Column))
            Do
                iC = iC + 1 'just to set the counter
            Loop While arrayF(iC) <> i.Value 'stop when gets equals and keep the counter

            'in the array the values are just strings,
            'but we know that is key-value pairs thats why adding +1 to iC we get the real info
            'below the label
            nR = colRowRange.Find(arrayF(iC + 1)).Row 'just used here
            nC = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(colRowRange, arrayF(iC + 1)) + nR - 1 'here we count to set the range
            Set colRowSubRange = Range(Cells(nR, i.Column), Cells(nC, i.Column)) 'set the range
            myRow = colRowSubRange.Row 'here we get the row of the value
        Else
            Do 'this is simpler
                iC = iC + 1
            Loop While arrayF(iC) <> i.Value 'againg...

            nR = colRowSubRange.Offset(, 1).Find(arrayF(iC + 1)).Row 'use the SubRange to get others subranges
            nC = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(colRowSubRange.Offset(, 1), arrayF(iC + 1)) + nR - 1
            Set colRowSubRange = Range(Cells(nR, i.Column), Cells(nC, i.Column))
            myRow = colRowSubRange.Row 'idem
        End If
    Next i


    numCols = thePivot.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count 'other part of the pivot... (see the picture (2))
    Set theRNG = thePivot.DataBodyRange.Resize(1, numCols) 'just take the above labels
    Set theRNG = theRNG.Offset(-1, 0)
    iC = -1

        For Each L In thePivot.ColumnFields 'for every label...
            Do
                iC = iC + 1
            Loop While L <> arrayF(iC) 'idem
            myCol = theRNG.Find(arrayF(iC + 1), , , xlWhole).Column
            'always will be just one column...
        Next L
    Cells(myRow, myCol).ShowDetail = True 'here is the magic!!! show all the data
End Sub
```

And inside the Worksheet code this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Left(Target.Formula, 13) = "=GETPIVOTDATA" Then 'Check if there a formula GetPivotData
        getDataFromFormula Sheets(Me.Name), Target
    End If
End Sub
```

See this picture to understand what happends to the formula:

[image]

The formula is split it as you can see `f`, into `arrayF`.

I'm sure you will need to do some changes, but this is very functional and basic, and will be easy to findout what you need.

Also:

This part of code helps me a lot to understand what the pivot had. Using the same data and pivot, I ran the code:

```
Sub rangePivot()
    Dim Pivot As PivotTable
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim P As Worksheet
    Dim D As Worksheet
    Dim S As Worksheet
    Dim i
    Set P = Sheets("P") 'the sheet with the pivot
    Set D = Sheets("D") 'the sheet with the data
    Set S = Sheets("S") 'the sheet with the cells with the formula
    S.Activate 'go
    Set Pivot = P.PivotTables("PivotTable1") 'store the pivot here...

    For i = 1 To Pivot.RowFields.Count
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Pivot.RowFields(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.ColumnFields.Count
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Pivot.ColumnFields(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataFields.Count
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Pivot.DataFields(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataLabelRange.Count
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Pivot.DataLabelRange.Address(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataLabelRange.Count
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Pivot.DataLabelRange.Address(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataFields.Count
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Pivot.DataFields(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataFields.Count
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Pivot.DataFields(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataFields.Count
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Pivot.DataFields(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataBodyRange.Count
        Cells(i, 6).Value = Pivot.DataBodyRange.Address(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To Pivot.DataLabelRange.Count
        Cells(i, 7).Value = Pivot.DataLabelRange.Address(i)
    Next i
    Cells(1, 8).Value = Pivot.ColumnGrand
    Cells(1, 9).Value = Pivot.RowRange.Address
    Cells(1, 11).Value = Pivot.TableRange1.Address
    Cells(1, 12).Value = Pivot.TableRange2.Address
End Sub
```

And, as usual, if you need som help & improvement contact me. Hope this help other too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do VBA you could set up an event like here:

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=49050

Once you have that set up you need to develop some code that determines where the subtotal cell is (because those are prone to change).  Once you have that address you can use `Range([subtotal]).ShowDetail = True`